# How to store and retrieve the string with special characters in php?

Tags: php

How to store and retrieve a string in this format using php, and I have tried the following the code,

```
   $description="Welcome to our "world". Some text here! Some text'here!.";

   $description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);

   $description = preg_replace("/&[a-z]+;/i"," ",$description);
```

I am using the same variable `$description` for store and retrieve values in database.In my code not print the single quote.

**Need to retrieve the Output :**
`Welcome to our "world". Some text here! Some text'here!.`

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful mysql_real_escape_string is now deprecated. Try to use mysqli_real_escape_string ([mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)) For your simple quote problem, try to add a \ just before it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code, as it stands, will error. If you include a `"` character in a string literal delimited with `"` characters then you have to escape them so they count as data and not the end of the string.

```
$description="Welcome to our \"world\". Some text here! Some text'here!.";
```

> I am using the same variable $description for store and retrieve values in database

If you are having problems inserting data into a database, then you should include the code you are using to try to do that.

You should not be using `mysql_real_escape_string` (which is for preparing data to be inserted into a MySQL database when you are using an [an obsolete database API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068)). Use a [modern API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068).)

You do not need to remove HTML entities from the string. (Your example doesn't have any anyway). If you are dealing with user input data, then you should use a non-destructive way to deal with them (which usually means, if you want to treat the input as text, escaping them with `htmlspecialchars` *immediately* before inserting them into an HTML document (not before inserting them into a database).

Answer (score 0):

```
$description="Welcome to our "world". Some text here! Some text'here!.";


should be

$description="Welcome to our \"world\". Some text here! Some text'here!.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you use ADOdb? This would abstract the db implementation details and I think your needed feature is built-in there.